# How do I use Jquery and Jquery-ui with wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I have a website and I'm trying to add some things that I have coded, and have used jquery and jquery-ui, when i was writing up the code i simply used the following links to files in my computer to access jquery and jquery ui:

```
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

However with wordpress that doesn't work and I've searched online for no clear answers, I've come across lots of functions (that vary!) as well as php. I've looked at source code of other websites and many other things but can't get a simple solution and every time I try it doesn't work either.

Perhaps the solution is complicated, if so I'm willing to learn but I need to know where to begin.

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: You can use `jquery` and `jquery-ui` libraries same as you do in core php. You can add those links in header file of your theme.

Comment: I know barely anything about php, but ok so add in the header the above links? I don't think they'd work since they're the ones saved on my laptop, are there any specific links that I'd need?

Comment: Could you please attach your HTML page with links to js files? Maybe on the page uploaded to server links_to_js_files are pointing to files on your local machine (Hosted libraries should be used. They can be found on this page: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

Comment: That's it! I was linking to my local machine, I knew it was wrong but didn't know what else to link to. So now I've have linked the two files (as well as the jquery-ui css stylesheet which i was wondering about as well) however it still doesn't work... It's a start though, cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can (should) do it like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
```

This will add jquery and jquery-ui that are included with your WP version.

Refer to [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) to see other scripts included in WP.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your functions.php file:

```
function test_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_name_scripts' );
```

For more information please refer below link.
    https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0):

As addition to Flyer answer, which is correct (you don't need to include jquery as external file, it's already inside WP core, you just have to enqueue it) ; you'll probably need to encapsulate your jQuery code inside a closure to make `$` recognized:

```
(function($){
  // your jquery code here
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can enqueue script using `<?php wp_enqueue_script(); ?>` in functions.php file of you template like this

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

more reading here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: @vard yes it does, but if you code is dependent on other versions of jquery you have to include it too in your theme

Comment: Then it's not the right way to proceed - you have to deregister the default jquery first and name the new one as jquery or other enqueues that require jquery will fail.

Comment: I vary much agree with you, but I have come across situations where I have to include 2 versions of jquery as one jquery Plugin in not compatible with other version of jquery, and other jquery plugin is not compatible with the default jquery.

Answer (score -1):

You can add like below as described https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```